# Move and fixed scrollbar to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move the scrollbar on the bottom of the page same like bitbucket did on there jira software. I tried use different display but it seem it is not correct. Here's my code.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="card animate__animated animate__backInUp bg-color-mode">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="f-color-mode">Complete List</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="search"
                        name="search"
                        placeholder="Search..."
                    />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="overflow: auto">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                    <table
                        id="table-data"
                        class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm"
                        style="width: 100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Name</th>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Address</th>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Contact Number</th>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Email</th>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Juan Dawn Tsubaka</td>
                            <td>Mrs Smith 98 Shirley Street PIMPAMA QLD 4209 AUSTRALIA</td>
                            <td>+61 3 1234 1234</td>
                            <td>test@verylongdomaingoeshere.com</td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="#"
                                ><i
                                class="feather mr-2 icon-edit fa-lg btn-action"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top"
                                title="Update"
                                ></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#"
                                ><i
                                class="feather mr-2 icon-trash fa-lg btn-action btn-red"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top"
                                title="Delete"
                                ></i>
                            </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see also the screenshot here for reference

[image: screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 0):

I added on your white-space:nowrap add the overflow-x auto on the footer..See below if this is what you mean??

```css
footer {overflow-x: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" > 
    <div class="card animate__animated animate__backInUp bg-color-mode">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="f-color-mode">Complete List</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="search"
                        name="search"
                        placeholder="Search..."
                    />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                    <table
                        id="table-data"
                        class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm"
                        style="width: 100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Name</th>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Address</th>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Contact Number</th>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Email</th>
                            <th role="button" class="bg-table table-color-mode">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Juan Dawn Tsubaka</td>
                            <td>Mrs Smith 98 Shirley Street PIMPAMA QLD 4209 AUSTRALIA</td>
                            <td>+61 3 1234 1234</td>
                            <td>test@verylongdomaingoeshere.com</td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="#"
                                ><i
                                class="feather mr-2 icon-edit fa-lg btn-action"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top"
                                title="Update"
                                ></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#"
                                ><i
                                class="feather mr-2 icon-trash fa-lg btn-action btn-red"
                                data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="top"
                                title="Delete"
                                ></i>
                            </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i tried your code but still  the scroll bar is inside the card class.  I want to be in the footer and fixed on that part.

Comment: I edited the code let me know if that works for you.